# How to add return value to stored procedure parameter in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, ado.net

I am trying to invoke a stored procedure in my database I have called InsertJ in c#.
My procedure has an output parameter, which is an integer.

When I run my program, and input the values to insert, I get an exception sayings: InsertJ expects parameter '@code' which was not supplied.

To my knowledge I am supplying it correctly.  Can anyone help me figure out what im doing wrong?

```
 if(input == "insert")
     {
     insertCmd = new SqlCommand(insertStmt, conn);
     insertCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    insertCmd.Parameters.Add("@jnum", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5);
    insertCmd.Parameters.Add("@jname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
    insertCmd.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
    SqlParameter ret = insertCmd.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.Int);//here
    ret.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;//here
    insertCmd.Prepare();
```

Comment: What about setting ParameterDirection.Output? It's been a while since I've dealt with ado.net; forget if this is the problem.

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil YEs that worked! Put that as an answer and ill chose it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ret.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

should be:

```
ret.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```